# Регулярное выражение цифры или цифры, пробелы, скобки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Привет, нужно пропустить поле формы, только в том случае, если оно содержит 
(только цифры) или (цифры, буквы, пробел, скобки, -, +).

Последовательность не имеет значения. (нестрогая проверка номера телефона).

Вот такой шаблон работает

```
!/[^0-9a-z\(\)\-\+\s]/i.test('8(911) 000 00-00'); //true
```

но этот же шаблон пропустит только буквы (как и только скобки и т. д.)

```
!/[^0-9a-z\(\)\-\+\s]/i.test('test'); //true
```

Догадываюсь, что надо использовать группировку, но как это сделать элегантно и лаконично,  пока не понял.

Подскажите шаблон пожалуйста.
Спасибо.

Comment: Может, просто запретить чисто буквенные строки: [`/^(?![a-z]+$)[0-9a-z()+ -]+$/ig`](https://regex101.com/r/aF8iS6/2)? Вопрос не до конца ясен.

Comment: Гораздо элегантнее на каждый onChange для поля ввода удалять все, кроме цифр.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если предположить что телефон все таки должен начинаться с цифры, то регулярное выражение может выглядеть как то так:

```
/^[\+\(]{0,1}[\d]+[a-z\(\)\-\+\s]*/ig
```

Переписал с учетом комментария splash58

Comment: а почему не со скобки - например,  с кода города?

Answer (score 0):

Регулярка проверяет чтобы была хотя бы 1 цифра. Остальные символы по требованию автора вопроса:

```
 /^(?=.*[0-9])[0-9a-z \(\)\+-]+$/i
```

Comment: Можно еще сюда посмотреть http://habrahabr.ru/post/110731/